# Get php outputs sorted by smallest value

Tags: php, sql, database

I have this code in my html

```html
<h3>Top Pilots</h3>
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div class="span3">
  <table width="100%">
   <thead><tr><td align="center" colspan="3">Best Landings This Month</td></tr></thead>
   <?php 
   $dbm="SELECT DISTINCT pilotid FROM phpvms_pireps WHERE date_format(submitdate, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') ORDER BY landingrate DESC";
   $bstm = DB::get_results($dbm);
   $num = count($bstm);
   foreach ($bstm as $btm)
    {
     $d1m=$btm->pilotid;
     $blm1="SELECT * FROM phpvms_pilots WHERE pilotid = '$d1m' ";
     $blm2="SELECT * FROM phpvms_pireps WHERE pilotid = '$d1m' AND date_format(submitdate, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') ORDER BY landingrate DESC";
     $pblm1 = DB::get_row($blm1);
     $pblm2 = DB::get_row($blm2);
     if($pblm2->landingrate == 0){continue;}
     
   ?>
     <tr><td></td><td><?php echo $pblm1->firstname.' '.$pblm1->lastname ;?></td><td align="center"><font color="#009900"><?php echo sort($pblm2->landingrate) ;?> ft/min</font></td></tr>
   <?php 
    } 
   ?>
   
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

And I get the results just fine like this:

[image]

This is the structure of my 2 tables. First one is PIREPS second one is PILOTS

[image]

[image]

But I need to sort them in order from smallest to largest numbers. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please show us, what have you tried already? Also, your code snippet contains PHP code, please include the actual HTML output.

Comment: Are you not already doing it in the SQL ? What is the output of the SQL?

Comment: is landingrate is stored with ft/min or without ft/min means only numeric value?

Comment: are there multiple results for one pilot? If yes: you want to get the largest number for each pilot? btw: I wouldn't use two sql requests, can't yo deal with one request only?

Comment: Please show us the table structure for the two tables

Comment: Guys I provided the whole code and an image as the results. If you look at the code PHP and HTML are mixed in one <div> tag.

Comment: @fjellfly yes each pilot has multiple outputs that's why I used DISTINCT in my query and I'm getting the largest number for each pilot all right.

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal the ft/m is just a print out after the value is pulled.

Comment: Something like this should work: `SELECT B.firstname,B.lastname,MAX(A.landingrate) FROM phpvms_pireps AS A, phpvms_pilots AS B WHERE A.pilotid = B.pilotid GROUP BY A.pilotid` but sry, i wasn't able to test it... Maybe you can test it in phpmyadmin :-)

I used the MAX()-function to get the maximum landing rate and group by instead of distinct. As a benefeit you have it in one query now, which simplifys your php-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace first query:

```
$dbm="SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT 
         pilotid, min(landingrate) as landingrate 
         FROM phpvms_pireps 
         WHERE date_format(submitdate, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') and landingrate <> 0 
         GROUP BY pilotid) t1 
    ORDER BY landingrate DESC";
```

Replace min() with max() if you have negative values.
In foreach remove $blm2 query and display $btm->landingrate

You can also replace $blm1 with apropriate JOIN in first query

```
$dbm="SELECT t1.pilotid,t1.landingrate,t2.firstname,t2.lastname FROM 
    (SELECT 
         pilotid, min(landingrate) as landingrate 
         FROM phpvms_pireps 
         WHERE date_format(submitdate, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') and landingrate <> 0 
         GROUP BY pilotid) t1
    LEFT JOIN phpvms_pilots t2 ON t1.pilotid = t2.pilotid 
    ORDER BY landingrate DESC";
```

It also give better performance - only 1 query.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with one sql and use JOIN. And just use $pblm1;

```
$blm1="SELECT * FROM phpvms_pilots,phpvms_pireps 
WHERE pilotid = '$d1m' 
AND date_format(submitdate, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m') 
AND phpvms_pilots.pilotid = phpvms_pireps.pilotid  
ORDER BY landingrate DESC";
```